# R function for a number sequence

Tags: r, function, sequence

I have a those sequences:

1. `1,2,3,13,14,15,25,26,27`
2. `1,2,3,4,14,15,16,17,27,28,29,30,40,41,42,43`

they are constructed as follows:

1. I choose a number M (for example: 3) and a start number F (for example: 1);
2. I make the power of 2 of this number M^2 (3*3=9) and it is the length of the sequence;
3. The number in the sequence are in arithmetic progression with "GI" increment (for example: 1) but the number in M+1, 2M+1 and so on, position is the previous number + "P2I" increment (for example: 10) [(F=)1, (1+GI=)2, (2+GI=)3, (3+P2I=)13, (13+GI=)14, ...]

How I make a function that prints those sequences?

Thanks

Comment: Your example sequences don't match up with your third construction instruction (e.g., 3+GI+P21 = 3+1+10 = 14, not 13). It would be much easier to interpret your instructions if you provided a few inputs with varying input parameters and show the corresponding output. For the first example provided, is that M = 3, F = 1, GI = 1, P21 = 10? What would be the expected output for M = 3, F = 1, GI = 2, P21 = 10?

Comment: @jblood94 you are right. It is only (3+P2I=)13.  With  M = 3, F = 1, GI = 1, P21 = 10 sequence is: 1 2 3 13 14 15 25 26 27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `sequence` function:

```
fSeq <- function(M, F, GI, P21) {
  sequence(rep(M, M), seq(F, by = (M - 1)*GI + P21, length.out = M), GI)
}

fSeq(3, 1, 1, 10)
#> [1]  1  2  3 13 14 15 25 26 27
fSeq(4, 1, 1, 10)
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4 14 15 16 17 27 28 29 30 40 41 42 43
```

Using `row` and `col`:

```
fSeq2 <- function(M, F, GI, P21) {
  m <- matrix(F - GI*M - P21, nrow = M, ncol = M)
  return(c(m + row(m)*GI + col(m)*(GI*(M - 1) + P21)))
}

fSeq2(3, 1, 1, 10)
#> [1]  1  2  3 13 14 15 25 26 27
fSeq2(4, 1, 1, 10)
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4 14 15 16 17 27 28 29 30 40 41 42 43
```

With `cumsum`:

```
fSeq3 <- function(M, F, GI, P21) {
  cumsum(c(F - P21 + GI, rep(GI, M^2 - 1)) + c(P21 - GI, rep(0, M - 1)))
}

fSeq3(3, 1, 1, 10)
#> [1]  1  2  3 13 14 15 25 26 27
fSeq3(4, 1, 1, 10)
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4 14 15 16 17 27 28 29 30 40 41 42 43
```

Comment: Is it possible without use the sequence function?

Comment: Sure. There are many ways to do it. See the updated answer.

Comment: @GregorThomas not a homework, just for diversion.

Comment: Very surprising. The *"Okay, but now do it without `sequence`* seems very homework-assignmenty.